# Allowing remote desktop over 2 different NICs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have 2 networks plugged into a server 2008 R2 box. Both are separate vlans with internet connections. I want network B to be able to remote desktop into the server using IP 10.20.0.16 and network A remote desktop into it via 10.10.0.16.

NIC A has the IP, default gateway, and DNS servers set up. NIC B just has IP and default gateway (NO DNS). Metric is statically set with NIC A being 20 and NIC B being 40.

The server isn't really used for internet access, just for internal traffic. Is there anything I need to be worried about by having two default gateways set up?

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.10.0.1    10.10.0.16    276
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.20.0.1       10.20.0.16    296
        10.20.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.20.0.16    296
       10.20.0.16  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.0.16    296
      10.20.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.0.16    296
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.18.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     10.10.0.16    276
    10.10.0.16  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.0.16    276
   10.10.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.0.16    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.10.0.16    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.20.0.16    296
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.0.16    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.20.0.16    296
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.10.0.1  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.20.0.1  Default
```

Comment: If the clients connecting to the server via either interface are local to those interfaces (in the same subnet) then you don't need a default gateway at all on either NIC.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong exactly?  Can you not RDP into both IPs from their respective networks?  If not, you need to fix whatever routing/vlan/network issue is preventing RDP via their IP addresses.

Once that's settled, on whatever DNS servers service network A and B, put in static DNS host A records if you wish for each of the NICs based on the DNS name you want them to use.

For instance, network A's nic could be "RDPServerA.domain.com" and network B's nic could be "RDPServerB.domain.com".  Both would technically achieve access to the same server/resources, just one network would access it from NIC A and the other from NIC B.